# Fragments and Thread in Android

Tags: android, multithreading, android-fragments

I have a fragment[MainMenu] which has just menus and background image.I want to load the MainMenu fragment image and after some time i want to load the menus one by one after certain interval. And I tired to do this:

```
public class MainMenu extends Fragment{

public MainMenu(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_menu, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(final View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        ShowMenu(view);
    }

    private static void ShowMenu(final View container){

        String[] menu = container.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.array_menu_string);

        final LinearLayout llMenu = (LinearLayout)container.findViewById(R.id.llButtons);

        for(int i = 0; i<menu.length; i++){
            final String menuName = menu[i];
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                TextView tvMenu = new TextView(container.getContext());
                tvMenu.setText(menuName);
                tvMenu.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
                llMenu.addView(tvMenu);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                System.out.println(menuName);

            }
        }

    }
}
```

But the problem is the menus are already loaded then only the fragment is displayed? Please help to understand me why is this happening... and what should be done?

Comment: you are using Thread.sleep(2000); in your main thread arent you getting exception?? if not then I guess your device is gingerbread

Comment: @IllegalArgument its kitkat